# c++ confused with matching the types

Tags: c++, types

I don't understand how the types of the priority queue allows for the call to push? I don't see how the types match up and why passing these arguments to push works

Code:

```
int V, S; cin >> V >> S;

vector<vector<int>> sell(V);
for (int i=0; i<V; i++) {
    int c; cin >> c;
    sell[i].resize(c);
    for (int& s : sell[i]) {
        cin >> s; s--;
    }
}

const int64_t INF = 1e12;
tensor<int64_t, 2> stone_dist({S, V}, INF);

priority_queue<pair<int64_t, pair<int, int>>, vector<pair<int64_t, pair<int, int>>,
greater<>> pq

for (int i=0; i<V; i++) {
    for(int s: sell[i]) {
        /* the line below is what I really don't get,
         * how are the types passed in matching with that of pq? */
        pq.push({stone_dist[{s,i}] = 0, {s,i}});
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a long and complicated story. Read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion for starters.

Comment: I don't really need to know indepth I just want to know that this simplifies to this and equals that type

Comment: It would improve the question to post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This question depends on what "tensor" is, for example

Comment: Also there is a syntax error on the line starting `priority_queue<`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the tensor class, but I guess it creates a 2D array filled with int64_t.

```
stone_dist[{s,i}] = 0
```

means you initialize the element s,i in your array with the value 0 and you return 0 at the same time, which is an int64_t.

```
{s,i}
```

returns a pair<int,int>

```
{stone_dist[{s,i}] = 0, {s,i}}
```

is equivalent to

```
{0, {s,i}}
```

which is a pair< int64_t, pair<int,int> >, which is the element used inside your priority_queue ( = the first part of the priority_queue definition : <element_type, container, comparator> )

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions about the real code ,  the problem boils down to how this code works:

```
using Foo = std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>>;
Foo bar{ 0, {1, 2} };
```

Bearing in mind that initialization of a reference from a braced list or a prvalue expression works the same as initialization of an object of the referenced type , except that we conceptually initialize a temporary of the referenced type for the reference to bind to. (i.e. `int&& x = 0;` is basically the same as `int x = 0;`).

---

Here we have list-initialization of  a non-aggregate class. To cut a long story short, this works by trying each constructor of the class and seeing if the list is a valid initializer for that constructor.  The elements of the list are matched in order against the parameters of the constructor.

In general this might also be involved constructors taking `std::initializer_list`, however `std::pair` has none of those. In other words, the code will behave the same as: `Foo bar( 0, {1, 2} );`.

Here the [constructor of `std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) that will be selected is:

```
constexpr pair( const T1& x, const T2& y );
```

where the initialization works because `0` is a valid initializer for `const int&`,  and `{1, 2}` is a valid initializer for `const std::pair<int, int>&`  .  The explanation of the latter is the same as just explained above.